# How do I know if someone is cryptojacking my system?

Tags: battery, system, malware, antivirus

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and updated. I found my pc fan running whenever it wanted and also i saw my battery getting draining very fast. Can someone help me solve this issue. I also saw my network port issues. I turned the livepatch on.

Comment: Maybe a driver issue. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-batterylife.html and https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/improve-battery-life-linux

Comment: Does running top from the command line provide any clues? e.g. a process consuming a lot of your CPU?

Comment: If this is a new installation and you've only installed software from official sources and haven't blindly executed scripts or commands that you found on the internet, the likelihood of your system being compromised is slim to none.  Ubuntu is very secure unless/until you make it less secure.